# PHP and jQuery: show/edit CSV file

Tags: php, jquery, csv

I have on my web server a PHP file and a CSV file.
When the web page is accessed, the PHP page reads the CSV line by line, and puts each line into a row of a table.
This works very well.

Now I want to have a couple enhancements.

a) below the table, I have in each column a text box where the user can enter some text, and a "Save" button. By clicking the button, I want the entered text inserted into the table and the CSV. Preferably without reloading the entire page. I believe inserting into the table works with jQuery, but how shall I deal with adding the row to the CSV?

b) on each row of the table, I want a "Delete" button. Upon clicking, the associated row shall be removed from the table. This works, I think, also with jQuery, but how to deal with the CSV?

I am not sure if the best idea is simply always completely rewriting the entire CSV, based on the table, instead of dealing with individual rows.

Comment: _"I am not sure if the best idea is simply always completely rewriting the entire CSV, based on the table, instead of dealing with individual rows."_ You are correct: it's much easier to simply rewrite the entire CSV file. Keep in mind that if more than one person is updating the table you will have issues in which one person's page is out of sync with another person's.

Comment: perfect. Could you give a hint what would be the most elegant way of doing this?

Comment: You're asking a very general question, to which I can only give a general response: Every time the user hits "Save" or "Delete", use AJAX to call a script that takes the appropriate action. If the script returns a status indicating success, update the screen accordingly or show an error message. If you want help with code you've written, please edit your question to show us the code and describe exactly what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks. I made some experiments. I used the template "AdminLTE", and I pushed my experimental results to Github: https://github.com/tcpluess/adminlte_test
The important files are index.php and dhcp.php. (I want to use this in the end to view leses of my DHCP Server and edit its configuration). Posting of the config works by AJAX POST Method, and the dhcp.php file writes the results to the file. Is this an acceptable approach, or is this "wrong", even though it works?

Comment: If you want help with your code you should [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77708203/edit) to include the code. Posting links to external sites is not a good idea because that code may disappear in the future. Anyway, if your code works, it's not really "wrong".